# Multiline unbuffered code in jade templates

Tags: node.js, pug

I am trying to write a template that renders a double indexed array. So I started writing this:

```
- var grid = [[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]];
each row in grid
    each cell in row
        if cell
            span x
        else
            span o
```

but this is not how I want to write my array
I want to write it like this:

```
- var grid = [[1, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 0]];
```

This doesn't work because jade is already out of the inline javascript

```
- var grid = [[1, 0, 1],
             - [0, 1, 0]];
```

This doesn't work because jade considers those two incorrect lines instead of one line

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: Yay, these are real!  Go check out the other answer on how to pull this off.

Sadly, this is currently not possible in Jade.  TJ (the maintainer) has stated that he does not care about this, but would welcome a feature request.  https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/796

Fortunately, you can declare the array in your JS file and pass it as a variable to Jade.

Comment: Ok. Could you give an example? If I out a variable into a js file, the variable is wrapped into a function definition during the compile process (I think it is a module then...). I am using brunch with jade. How can I directly include a js (or JSON file from jade)?

Comment: @NerDoc that sort of thing (passing variables to Jade) is covered in the docs: http://jade-lang.com/reference/

Comment: Aaaaah. I must have overlooked, that [includes](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/) does cover text includes - so if I understand correctly, I can use `script \n include blah.js` to have the variables directly in the current file, right?

Comment: This does not work. when I include a file that contains `var blah = 5;`, I can not access the variable *blah* from within the parent file. I'm not fluent in Js (as you might think)... could you give me a hint here?

Comment: @NerDoc I assume you are referring to including it within a script tag as in your previous comment? Then no - the variable would not be available to Jade at compile time. Instead it would be declared within the context of the browser. Jade is an amazing and beautiful templating language IMO but it can also be easy to get yourself into slightly confusing situations such as this.

Comment: First of all, Jade v1.11.0 supports multiline (block) unbuffered code. Second of all, how would one go about declaring an array in your JS file and then passing it as a variable to Jade? JS file is client-side, Jade is server-side.

Comment: @chharvey This answer was written long before 1.11.0 was released, no need to downvote.  I've updated it to point at the other answer.

Comment: @SomeKittens It is our responsibility as members of the SO community to upvote good and current answers, and downvote bad or outdated answers. This enforces the content on the site to be continually updated and of nothing less than the best quality. Thank you for editing your answer, as that is *exactly* what should be done in a situation like this. Hopefully with the new edit, other users are more likely to reconsider their previous vote and change it if necessary.

Answer (score 9):

Update: Multiline defs are now working for me using Jade `1.11.0`. Even nested JSON now works like a charm.

```
-
  projects = [{
    title: "Project 1",
    classname: "project1",
    slides: [{
      title: "Slide 1"
      img: "images/hello.png"
    },{
      title: "Slide 2"
      img: "images/world.png"
    }]
  }, {
    title: "Project 2",
    classname: "project2",
    slides: [{
      title: "Slide 3"
      img: "images/fun.png"
    },{
      title: "Slide 4"
      img: "images/things.png"
    }]
  }]
```